# Trigger Events to change database record in Node JS when reached a future dateTime

Tags: javascript, postgresql, triggers, nestjs, prisma

I am developing a functionality to the users where they add a task to database with `DateTime` field
,and when the `DateTime` reached it triggers event that change a filed in other table from "enabled" to "disabled" ,Plus the user can cancel this task before it happen.
so how  can I trigger this functionality know that my stack is , NodeJs with NestJs and Prisma ProstgreSql.
i checked @nestjs/schedule and node/cron it seems it's difficult to handel task canceling or recreate the job when the server restart.
any recommendation for NPM packages would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use NestJS lifecycle triggers like **onApplicationBootstrap**

- Get closest task or bunch of tasks from DB on server run,
- Add wait function. Like **wait(task, time)**
- Execute task (Change fields by update)
- On update callback get next task from DB and wait again

For stop execution of some DB records add boolean field like **execute: false** and change it by your API. On next cycle filter records by this field.